# Unable to return binary data from rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, gmail-api

I have stored a base64url_encoded string into a postgres database by using `binary` data type in rails. Here is the migration

```
def change
  add_column :gmail_attachments, :base64_data, :binary
end
```

The data I'm storing is coming as a base64 url encoded string from [gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages.attachments). When I tried to store the data as a `string` data type in postgres, I got

> ArgumentError (string contains null byte)

So, I went with binary data type and it was stored successfully into database. Now, when I try

```
render status: 200, json: gmail_attachment_record
```

I get the following error

> Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8):

How do I get rid of this error and return the stored data? Have I stored it in a wrong data type? What would be the best choice in rails ActiveRecord data types for achieving this?

Comment: http://www.nishantnigam.in/2012/01/sending-binary-data-over-network-with.html

- check if this article helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save a model with a `:binary` column, Rails is going to do all the work for you making sure that encodings are set appropriately to ensure your data is persisted correctly.

I believe you're getting the encoding error because the `to_json` method (implicitly called via `render`) is attempting to convert your binary string to UTF-8 via `JSON.encode`.  That's why you're getting the UndefinedConversionError.  (ASCII-8BIT is a special encoding in ruby that essentially means BINARY.)

---

To get to a working state, I think you're going to want to:

- persist your data to a binary column, like you did above - consider naming it `data`.  (Even better, use ActiveStorage and persist it to a file elsewhere.)  I'd recommend you  first convert your data from base64 to the raw binary representation:

```rb
# Not sure what the api exactly looks like, but you get the idea
require('base64')

base64_data = Gmail.get_attachment(...)

gmail_attachment.data = Base64.decode64(base64_data) # now our data field is just the raw bytes.
gmail_attachment.save
```

- Then you'll want to serialize that back to base64 for transmission via `to_json`.  You can do that through the `as_json` method like this:

```rb
# models/gmail_attachment.rb
require('base64')

class GmailAttachment < ApplicationRecord

  def base64_data
    Base64.encode64(self.data)
  end
end

# controllers/your_controller.rb
render json: gmail_attachment_record.as_json(except: [:data], methods: [:base64_data])
```

Pretty sure that should get you headed in the right direction!

Comment: thanks Mark G. it worked perfectly. However, I'm having trouble with syntax in the actual code that I'm writing. Please see my code with the error here
https://0bin.net/paste/pWfzbESs#+v6FYRm8xlfq3ELAELH3iQsRcI47nPd3OIst8hWUhk8

Comment: I can now return data but looks like it is not in the form that I intended to store it as. The data I receive is in ASCII-8BIT(i.e binary, do I still decode it using Base64.decode64(..)?) I tried both with and without decoding, and when I read it from db and encode with base64 it does not really take the form it is supposed to be. I verified this will online encoder/decoders and the data I'm getting is no where near to where its supposed to be,

Comment: Glad to hear it's almost working.

I thought the Gmail API returned base64 encoded data?  If that's the case, you need to decode it when you persist it to your database, as I suggested above.  When you send it through your rails controller, you then need to encode it.

Do you have an example that shows the discrepancy?  Happy to check out a gist/pastebin.

Comment: Please have a look here, it contains the actual Image's URL and the Gmail Attachment data I receive from the Gmail API. https://0bin.net/paste/0PhEzIaE#fIBMjjSUz-JV97KXca69NZt7yDBmyMDBbkwSN97xnzu